# Strange behavior Netbeans,GlassFish Java EE 7

Tags: jsf-2.2, netbeans-8, java-ee-7, glassfish-4

While I am developing Java EE application using GlassFish 4.2 and Netbeans 8.2, I faced many strange behaviors such as

1. any Edit any code not reflected to the web although DoS and Cos are enabled in Netbeans, and I have to build and run the application each time
2. `<f:validator binding="#{bean.validator}"/>` sometimes works and sometimes doesn't and many other things

I restarted the GF,NB but nothing, so can any one guide me in such problems?

**Note** I didn't post the `code` as it sometimes work and sometimes doesn't

Comment: So a plain jsp works all the time?

Comment: @Kukeltje thanks for interesting, in most times they work

Comment: If they fail at sort of the same rate, look at the generic problem...

Comment: So, What should I do? I didn't understand you well (: